# Trying to load & verify data WPF ( xaml ) connected to SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I'm trying to load & verify to create a login system for my App. But it seems that is not loading the user and password textbox.

Here's my C# code

```
private void btnAceptarLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox usuarioLogin = usuariosTextBox;
    TextBox passwordLogin = passwordTextBox;

    SqlConnection conexion  = new SqlConnection();
    conexion.ConnectionString = @"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=dolphinsplendidus_Plataforma1; Data Source=. \SQLEXPRESS";
    conexion.Open();

    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
    comando.CommandText = "SELECT [Usuario], [Password] FROM [DatosUsuarios]";
    comando.Connection = conexion;

    SqlDataReader lector = comando.ExecuteReader();

    while (lector.Read())
    {
      if (usuarioLogin == lector["Usuario"] && passwordLogin == lector["Password"])
      {
          VentanaPrueba venPrueba = new VentanaPrueba();
          venPrueba.ShowDialog();
      }
      else
      {
          MessageBox.Show("Introduzca un usuario y contraseña valido y/o contactese con el administrador");
          MessageBox.Show("Usuario: " + lector["Usuario"] + ", Password: " + lector["Password"]);
      }
    }
}
```

There's a method to see if TextBox's are Reading? I'm 99% sure the problem comes from those "TextBox"

In the .xaml is declared like these

Password TextBox = `<TextBox x:Name="passwordTextBox />`
User TextBox = `<TextBox x:Name="usuariosTextBox />`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: "But it seems that is not loading the user and password textbox" - What do you mean by this? What is the problem?

Comment: I mean the string it doesn't loaded correctly because it doesn't compare corrrectly the TextBox string with the data readed on the database. Sorry for the bad explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing an object of type `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox` with a variable of type `System.Object` which (I assume) happens to reference an instance of type `System.String`:

```
usuarioLogin == lector["Usuario"] && passwordLogin == lector["Password"])
```

This will return `false` because a `TextBox` can never be equal to a `String`.

**Quick solution:**

Use the `TextBox.Text` property instead:

```
usuarioLogin.Text == lector["Usuario"] && passwordLogin.Text == lector["Password"])
```

**Proper Solution:**

You seem to be lacking fundamental understanding of OOP, Separation of Concerns, and programming in general. I suggest you take the time to properly learn about OOP, implement a proper layered architecture that separates your DB code from the UI, use MVVM if you're using WPF, and stop writing SQL queries as strings and use an ORM such as Entity Framework.

Comment: Maybe this is just simple university project for laboratory or something. Don't judge him based on source code :)

Comment: @Fka `university project` - then it should be properly designed ;)

Comment: Yeah, but if it is for next day's morning - I don't care. But yes, people should learn basics. +1 for answer

Comment: Your quick solution doesn't Works, and if I'm asking a question is obvious that I don't know where's the problem, I've tried with the quick solution before I asked the question. The problem is that it doesn't read or won't compare that text its contained on textBox, and that's why it doesn't Works. Your proper solution doesn't help me to solution the problem. Anyway thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, SqlDataReader is an object thats why it doesn't read properly.

Here's the code for somebody that maybe will have the same problem in the future.

```
private void btnAceptarLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        SqlConnection conexion  = new SqlConnection();

        conexion.ConnectionString = @"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=dolphinsplendidus_Plataforma1; Data Source=. \SQLEXPRESS";

        conexion.Open();



        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
        comando.CommandText = "SELECT [Usuario], [Password] FROM [DatosUsuarios]";
        comando.Connection = conexion;



        SqlDataReader lector = comando.ExecuteReader();


        while (lector.Read())
        {
            string usuarioDatosUsuarios = lector["Usuario"].ToString();
            string passwordDatosUsuarios = lector["Password"].ToString();


            string usuarioLogin = usuariosTextBox.Text;
            string passwordLogin = passwordTextBox.Text;

            if (usuarioLogin == usuarioDatosUsuarios && passwordLogin == passwordDatosUsuarios)
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Bienvenido " + usuarioLogin);
              VentanaPrueba venPrueba = new VentanaPrueba();
              venPrueba.ShowDialog();

          }
          else
          {

              MessageBox.Show("Introduzca un usuario y contraseña valido y/o contactese con el administrador");

          }



        }




    }
```